# Cacti 1.2.10 и 1.2.11

Tags: snmp

Помогите плиз советом!

Поставил Cacti 1.2.10, настроил автоматический поиск девайсов с созданием девайсов в дереве.
Но проблема в том, что девайсы создаются в подпапках (с теми же именами).
Что это за новшество, и зачем его ввели, я не очень понимаю, но я очень верю в то, что можно его выключить. То же самое происходит и в 1.2.11.

Главное в том, что вручную девайсы создаются без подпапок.
Кто нашел как обойти это, очень жду совета!
Ниже на картинке слева создается автоматически в подпапках, а справа так как мне нужно, если создать вручную.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался со свой проблемой: не нужно было создавать елемент в "tree creation criteria". Эти элементы создают leaf(=подпапка) на каждый девайс.

[image: Tree creation criteria]
[image: структура дерева как мне нужно]